# ROS Fuerte in Multiple machines

Tags: ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

In ros fuerte i can't communicate from slave to the master! can someone help-me?

I have in the bash script for master this:

```
export ROS_IP=192.168.55.112
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.55.112:11311
```

at the slave the same. In the slave i make rostopic list and i see all publications.

but when i run a node, in the slave pc, that should publish something, the master can't ear anything! (if run the publisher in the master and subscriber in the slave it works, the inverse not!!!!)

If i run the same node in the master everything runs ok! What could be the problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34054/ros-fuerte-in-multiple-machines/) by [Filipe Santos](https://answers.ros.org/users/907/filipe-santos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 346 on 2012-05-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The slave should not export its IP to be the same as the master. It should export its own IP.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Filipe Santos](https://answers.ros.org/users/907/filipe-santos/) on 2012-05-15**:
thanks DimitriProsser, it was that mistake! :)

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-05-15**:
@Filipe Santos Please accept the answer so others know your question is solved. (Click the checkmark next to the answer.)